How do I get text from an embedded map on a website?
I have written a code that accesses a webpage and searches the page for the link to another website from the inspect element. After accessing that website, I need to get the zip code of an address from a map that is embedded on that web page. It is not available on the page source so i'm guessing it's dynamically loaded and i can't use BeautifulSoup for that.
For this i have used HTMLSession instead. I copied the XPATH to search for the tag and it was all fine. I got the link and was able to connect to the first web site.
Thing is, when i try to do the same for a map that is embedded on the page i landed on, i am unable to do the same XPATH search. It just returns an empty list or says 'NoneType object has no attribute .text' or something when i try to print it with print(zip_container.text).
I understand that the embedded map must be dynamically loaded and therefore i cannot use BeautifulSoup directly. What am i doing wrong?
I also cannot and do not want to use Selenium for this. I know it is possible with requests_html i just cant understand where i am going wrong.
Here is the code i have written, modules all imported already and code for the first webpage not posted since its irrelevant:
store_urls = 'https://www.miyazaki-recycle.com/recycling-station/14821/'

session = HTMLSession()
response =  session.get(store_urls, timeout=60)
response.html.render(sleep=10) 
zip_container = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="mapDiv"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]', first=True)
print(zip_container)

I have also tried using find as below but it doesn't work either :
zip_container = response.html.find('div.address', first=True)

Please let me know if any other information is required.
I'm also really new to python so go easy pls.

The expected data are in an iframe which you should select the iframe first:

Or you can intercept the response of the iframe request:

pls tell me if you need to verify the above methods using puppeteer or playwright.

Hey, thanks for the reply. What do you mean by verifying it using puppeteer or playwright? Im unsure of what either does but i do remember installing puppeteer a few weeks ago although i dont remember ever using it. Also, why did you circle 'mapDiv'?

The following template can extract the data: 31°23'09.8"N 130°53'55.9"E\n978-2 Tomiyama, Kimotsuki, Kimotsuki District, Kagoshima 893-1204, Japan
An open source nodejs package, based on puppeteer or playwright, can execute the following template.
Or you can use the loc and srcprefix in your code.
  <actions>
    <action_goto url="https://www.miyazaki-recycle.com/recycling-station/14821/" wait="5000"/>
    <action_extract tabname="dat_00000000000012ab">
      <column_element colname="c01" nickname="data">
        <element loc="div.place-desc-large">
          <iframe srcprefix="https://www.google.com/maps/" />
        </element>
      </column_element>
    </action_extract>
  </actions>


The data you need is actually loaded after the html rendering. But you don't need to use the requests-html library to get it, you just need to make one additional request. If you look in the loaded html, the data is loaded in the iframe tag, from which you can get a link to retrieve the data directly. It looks like this:

There are two iframe tags on the page, we need to find both of them and take the second one, which will be under index 1. After that, we get the reference src from this object and make another request. We get another html in response, which looks like this:

Now we need to get the data from this html which is passed to the initEmbed function, this is a json object and the easiest way to get it is to use a regular expression:
r'initEmbed\((.+?)\)'

Next, we parse the found string using json.loads. The data you need will be in a nested array, and the location of the data never changes. Therefore, we just look at what indexes can be used to "reach" the data. I have already checked this, the necessary data can be obtained by accessing the following indices: 21 -> 3 -> 13. As a result, your code will look something like this:
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    iframe_link = soup.find_all('iframe')[1]['src']
    data_response = requests.get(iframe_link)
    search_pattern = re.compile(r'initEmbed\((.+?)\)')

    result_data = search_pattern.search(data_response.text)
    if result_data is not None:
        data = json.loads(result_data.group(1))
        address = data[21][3][13]
        return address


#  978-2 Tomiyama, Kimotsuki, Kimotsuki District, Kagoshima 893-1204, Japan
print(parse('https://www.miyazaki-recycle.com/recycling-station/14821/'))

#  4-chōme-9-5 Hirota, Sasebo, Nagasaki 859-3223, Japan
print(parse('https://www.miyazaki-recycle.com/recycling-station/14959/'))

#  1-chōme-704-15 Kakomachi, Ōmura, Nagasaki 856-0827, Japan
print(parse('https://www.miyazaki-recycle.com/recycling-station/14979/'))

